# How to emulate QEMU to connect server sockets

Tags: sockets, networking, virtual-machine, qemu

I have set up a QEMU virtual machine (VM) trying to emulate an ARM Cortex-A9 cpu on my lubuntu VM (on VirtualBox). Using the kernel, initrd and image of this [article](https://people.debian.org/%7Eaurel32/qemu/armhf/), I start QEMU like this:

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a9
    -m 512 
    -kernel vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-vexpress 
    -initrd initrd.img-3.2.0-4-vexpress 
    -drive if=sd,file=debian_wheezy_armhf_standard.qcow2 
    -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2" 
    -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

After it boots up, I have configurated an static IP on the guest. Modifying the path `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.102
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.11
```

The VM lubuntu, is on the same IP range (192.168.0.1) and my goal is to be able to stablish a connection from QEMU VM to three server sockets which are on port 12000, 13000 and 14000 on the lubuntu VM.

Which parameters do i have to modify/add? I've been reading the [network documentation](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking) but any test i do, is not working.

**UPDATE 1**

Following @Peter Maydell advice i changed the network configuration to run a dhcp client instead of an static IP.

```
# /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

So when running `# ip a` i get the IP 10.0.2.15/24. Anyways, now I'm being able to reach every net from QEMU but, to be honest, i would prefer to set up a static IP.

Comment: Don't try to test user-mode networking with ping, it doesn't work. This is the second "note" in the first section of https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking

Comment: If I ping the host IP from QEMU, I can reach it. Then, how can I test the network connection between VMs? I have a NAT configured on lubuntu VM and it is getting the IP that QEMU sets, I guess that is the reason why I can reach QEMU VM from lubuntu VM.

Comment: Test the networking by trying to use the networking, ie make TCP connections from the QEMU VM to the destinations you want. It is only ping (i.e. ICMP packets) that don't work.

Comment: Finally I decided to start QEMU in the lubuntu virtual machine itself and I have access to all sockets as well as I can ping in all directions. But if I'm honest, I would really like to use that static IP to have all the virtual machines running in the same range since they are for the same project. Is there a step by step guide @Peter Maydell ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just pick an IP address at random for your guest. It has to match the fake network that user-mode networking creates, which is (as the wiki page you link to mentions) on 10.0.2.x by default. It will not (and should not be) on the same IP range as the host or this other VM. The simplest thing is to have the guest run a DHCP client, which will then be able to automatically pick up the right network config from the fake DHCP server that the user-mode networking sets up.

Cross-VM communication as you want should be doable. First check that you can connect from the host to those ports on the lubuntu VM. If you can't do that then you need to fix that VM's config first. Once that is working, then it should also work to connect from the in-QEMU guest to the lubuntu VM on the same IP address/port. This is because outbound connections from the QEMU user-mode-networked guest to either the host or to the outside world require no special configuration. It's only inbound connections to the QEMU guest that need hostfwd setup.

Comment: The problem is that the IP of the QEMU virtual machine must be that one. Could this be achieved by configuring the network as tap? As for communication between VM, I am able to connect from the host to those ports on the lubuntu VM but from the QEMU VM I have no connection to the outside, I imagine it is because of the IP address set.

Comment: Why must the IP of the QEMU virtual machine be that specific one? You *can* do more complicated things involving tap and setting up a bridge on the host so that your lubuntu VM and the QEMU VM are really on the same network. But that's massively more complicated, so don't do it if you can avoid it.

Comment: I updated the question following your tips.